# Editing a state array using buttons within a map of the array - react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, state

I am trying to make a sort of Instagram clone for a course(no backend required). I have made a simplified replica to demonstrate my issue and will provide it at the bottom of the question. I am using the `map` function to show all of the posts, which are stored in the `sampleArray`, which is a state variable in this case. I want to add one like to the post when the button is pressed, but react immediately throws an error(#185 minified): `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` My question is, how can I avoid this issue and achieve the desired like counter effect? I can rework the entire structure of my app if needed because it is small. Since I am a beginner, any other suggestions are greatly appreciated as well. Thank you in advance.

```
    state = {
        sampleArray: [
            {imgURL: "https://picsum.photos/200/300", likes: 5, index: 0},
            {imgURL: "https://picsum.photos/201/301", likes: 3, index: 1},
            ],
    }
    
    likePost = (i) => {
        let tempPost = this.state.sampleArray;
        tempPost[i].likes += 1;
        this.setState({
            sampleArray: tempPost,
        });
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                {this.state.sampleArray.map((post) => (
                    <View style={styles.postContainer}>
                        <Image
                            source={{ uri: post.imgURL }}
                            style={{ height: 140, width: 200 }}
                        />
                        <Button
                            title="Like Post" onPress={this.likePost(post.index)}
                        />
                    </View>
                ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens as your call to likePost sets the state. which rerenders the component, which again calls your likePost, as you're calling it in the render method, and not referring to it. So this ends up running in a loop.

I assume you would not want to keep the image details as state in the component eventually, rather have it somewhere in the localstorage on either redux or as AsyncStorage. Suggest you to make that switch now, remove the details from the state of this component, which gets rid of your need to set the state on likePost, which stops this infinite loop.